# Problem importing modul2s from boto

Tags: python, boto

I have installed boto like so: python setup.py install; and then when I launch my python script (that imports moduls from boto) on shell, an error like this shows up: ImportError: No module named boto.s3.connection

How to settle the matter?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed same problem at Ubuntu using `apt-get install python-boto`

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the Python script does not use your default `python` executable. Check the shebang on the first line of the script (on *nix) or the .py file association (on Windows) and run that against setup.py instead.